# 301 permanent redirection changing URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, redirection, 301-redirect

I changed category urls on site. Old are like this:

www.example-name.com/category-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/

www.example-name.com/category-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/subcategory-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/

New URLs:

www.example-name.com/category-name/

www.example-name.com/category/subcategory-name/

I removed "**-exactly-same-keywords**" from category URLs.

In my .htaccess I have this:

`# Category 301 redirection`

RewriteRule ^-some-category-suffix(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]

It is fine, if there is just one category level, it rewrite this:

www.example-name.com/category-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/

to:

www.example-name.com/category-name/

But, if there is more than one category level it removes only last

www.example-name.com/category-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/subcategory-name**-exactly-same-keywords**/

to:

www.example-name.com/category**-exactly-same-keywords**/subcategory-name/

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

How to rewrite (remove) all instances of "**-exactly-same-keywords**", if more than one in old URLs to new URLs without it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [N flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) to the RewriteRule, to make it repeat as many times as the rule matches.  I'm not sure how that flag interacts with the L and R flags; I would start by taking both of those out, getting the rule working, then seeing which of them you can put back in.